# getting "errorMessage": "'BadRequestException' object has no attribute 'message'",

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, python-3.9

call to http()URl & download the file in S3 bucket. its working. then in 2nd part i am calling guardduty & give location of s3 file to create threat intel set. while running code i am getting below error:-

```
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "'BadRequestException' object has no attribute 'message'",
  "errorType": "AttributeError",
  "requestId": "bec541eb-a315-4f65-9fa9-3f1139e31f86",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 38, in lambda_handler\n    if \"name already exists\" in error.message:\n"
  ]
}
```

i want to create threat intel set using the file which is in S3--(downloaded from the URl)
code:-

```
import boto3
from datetime import datetime
import requests.packages.urllib3 as urllib3

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    url='https://rules.emergingthreats.net/blockrules/compromised-ips.txt' # put your url here
    bucket = 'awssaflitetifeeds-security' #your s3 bucket
    key = 'GDfeeds/compromised-ips.csv' #your desired s3 path or filename

    s3=boto3.client('s3')
    http=urllib3.PoolManager()
    s3.upload_fileobj(http.request('GET', url,preload_content=False), bucket, key)
    
    #------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Guard Duty
    #------------------------------------------------------------------
    location = "https://s3://awssaflitetifeeds-security/GDfeeds/compromised-ips.csv"
    timeStamp = datetime.now()
    name = "TF-%s"%timeStamp.strftime("%Y%m%d")
    guardduty = boto3.client('guardduty')
    response = guardduty.list_detectors()

    if len(response['DetectorIds']) == 0:
        raise Exception('Failed to read GuardDuty info. Please check if the service is activated')

    detectorId = response['DetectorIds'][0]
    try:
        response = guardduty.create_threat_intel_set(
            Activate=True,
            DetectorId=detectorId,
            Format='FIRE_EYE',
            Location=location,
            Name=name
        )

    except Exception as error:
        if "name already exists" in error.message:
            found = False
            response = guardduty.list_threat_intel_sets(DetectorId=detectorId)
            for setId in response['ThreatIntelSetIds']:
                response = guardduty.get_threat_intel_set(DetectorId=detectorId, ThreatIntelSetId=setId)
                if (name == response['Name']):
                    found = True
                    response = guardduty.update_threat_intel_set(
                        Activate=True,
                        DetectorId=detectorId,
                        Location=location,
                        Name=name,
                        ThreatIntelSetId=setId
                    )
                    break

            if not found:
                raise

        #-------------------------------------------------------------------
        # Update result data
        #------------------------------------------------------------------
        result = {
            'statusCode': '200',
            'body':  {'message': "You requested: %s day(s) of /view/iocs indicators in CSV"%environ['DAYS_REQUESTED']}
        }
    except Exception as error:
        logging.getLogger().error(str(error))
        responseStatus = 'FAILED'
        reason = error.message
        result = {
            'statusCode': '500',
            'body':  {'message': error.message}
        }
    finally:
        #------------------------------------------------------------------
        # Send Result
        #------------------------------------------------------------------
        if 'ResponseURL' in event:
            send_response(event, context, responseStatus, responseData, event['LogicalResourceId'], reason)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting that error message is because the exception being returned from `guardduty.create_threat_intel_set` does not have the `message` attribute directly on the exception. I think you want either `error.response['Message']` or `error.response['Error']['Message']` for this exception case.

A couple of other suggestions:

- you should replace the `except Exception` which is matching the exception showing an already-existing name with something more targeted. I'd recommend looking at what exceptions the guardduty client can throw for the particular operation and catch just the one you care about.
- it is likely better to check that `error.response['Error']['Code']` is exactly the error you want rather than doing a partial string match.